# openssl s_server is expecting key and certificate in case of PSK cipher test

Tags: openssl, server, client

I am new to security domain,

In case of **PSK why openssl s_server is expecting certificate and key**. If I don't give then it gives error like below.

```
$ openssl s_server -psk fcc56e7668194a4775e5b36e2735551a -accept 1440
-cipher PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA 

Error opening server certificate private key file server.pem 139623549462168:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('server.pem','r')

139623549462168:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400: unable to load server certificate private key file
```

If I provide certificate then **openssl s_server** starts .

```
$ openssl s_server -psk fcc56e7668194a4775e5b36e2735551a -key key.pem
-accept 1440 -cipher PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA -psk_hint Client_identity
```

**openssl s_client** doesn't need ceritificate

```
$ openssl s_client -connect localhost:1440 -psk fcc56e7668194a4775e5b36e2735551a
```

I have following questions ?

1. **certificate and key is not going to be used in client, only PSK will be used then why s_server need certificate ?**
2. **Is this right approach to test PSK using openssl server and client.**
3. **I am using RSA key in case of openssl server to verify PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA cipher, is this right key format for this cipher to verify.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly use the `-nocert` option so that it will not try to load the default certificate:

```
$ openssl s_server -psk fcc56e7668194a4775e5b36e2735551a -accept 1440 \
   -cipher PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA \
   -nocert
Using default temp DH parameters
ACCEPT
```

> 1. certificate and key is not going to be used in client, only PSK will be used then why s_server need certificate ?

A TLS server is usually used with a certificate and therefore s_server expects one by default (and has a default path where it expects it). A TLS client is usually used without a certificate and therefore s_client does not expect one.

> 2. Is this right approach to test PSK using openssl server and client.

Apart from adding the `-nocert` option and omitting the certificate, yes.

> 3. I am using RSA key in case of openssl server to verify PSK-AES128-CBC-SHA cipher, is this right key format for this cipher to verify.

No certificate is used when using PSK which means no RSA key is used too.